# How to include resources in a Mendix Pluggable Widget?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, mendix

We have an application and we’d like to create a Mendix custom widget to replicate one of it’s functionalities. At first I managed to do it by following a tutorial using dojo and no React, copying all the required JS files (2000+ files) into a *lib* folder in the widget, and referencing those in the app's index.html between `<script>` tags. This way the *lib* folder appeared in the generated .mpk file.

However now we'd like to isolate the dependencies in the widget and that's why I followed this tutorial: https://docs.mendix.com/howto/extensibility/create-a-pluggable-widget-one

I'd like now to copy the *lib* into the React component. This is how my folder structure looks like:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOzmm.png)

In `BeforeScriptSrc.jsx` and `AfterScriptSrc.jsx` I add some inline functions to the document's body. `ScriptSrc.jsx` is where my problem comes from:

```
export class ScriptSrc extends Component {

componentDidMount () {

    function createScript(src) {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.async = true;
        script.src = src;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    createScript("./lib/copiedJS.js");
    /*200 more of these*/
}

render() {
    return null;
}
```

}

When I build the component and synchronize the project directory in Mendix I get the following error in the console for every js file:

> 404 - file not found for file: lib/copiedJS.js

Also the *lib* folder doesn't appear in the generated widget. Is there a way to include this folder in the widget? Or any other ways to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the organisation?
I had more or less same issue and coul fix it by Changing json file
https://github.com/mendix/pluggable-widgets-generator/issues/15

Comment: Thanks for the response, I changed the organisation, but unfortunately the nature of my problem is different. I can see my components correctly but my imported js files don't show up. Changing the packagePath doesn't fix that.